# Facebook get al checked-in users

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, checkin

Is it possible to get a json list or something of all the users that have ever checked in to my page?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: No, that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get the list of users who have checked into a Place.

However, you can use the Tagged Places API to get the list of all the places that a particular person has been tagged at (aka checked in). See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/tagged_places